# Criar um dropdownlist e pegar o id selecionado Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso criar um `Dropdownlist` em tempo de execução com 2 opções de escolha.
Com isto, preciso fazer uma verificação pegando o registro selecionado e então acessar tal método.
Isso após clicar em uma `ActionLink`.

Como definir um id para esse `dropdownlist` para mexer nele? Como posso fazer isso?

Até agora eu fiz assim:

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.EscolhaBanco, new SelectList(new List<Object>
    {
         new {value = 0, text = ""},
         new {value = 1, text = "Bradesco"},
         new {value = 2, text = "Santander"}
    }, "value", "text", 0))
</td>

 <td>@Html.ActionLink("Imprimir", "ImprimirBoleto", new { Fatura = item.NumeroDocumento }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina um objeto anônimo no argumento `HtmlAttributes` da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.EscolhaBanco, new SelectList(new List<Object>
{
     new {value = 0, text = ""},
     new {value = 1, text = "Bradesco"},
     new {value = 2, text = "Santander"}
}, new { id = "IdDoMeuDropDownList" }))
```

---

**EDIT**

Para passar o valor selecionado para o *Controller*, você vai ter que usar um `<button>` ao invés de um `ActionLink`. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.EscolhaBanco, new SelectList(new List<Object>
    {
        new {value = 0, text = ""},
        new {value = 1, text = "Bradesco"},
        new {value = 2, text = "Santander"}
    }, "value", "text", 0))
    </td>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Não sei se você definiu uma *ViewModel* pra isso, mas o correto é definir a *ViewModel* e fazer a *View* usá-la:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.ViewModels
{
    public class EscolhaBancoViewModel 
    {
        public int EscolhaBanco { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A *View* fica assim:

```
@model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.EscolhaBancoViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.EscolhaBanco, new SelectList(new List<Object>
    {
        new {value = 0, text = ""},
        new {value = 1, text = "Bradesco"},
        new {value = 2, text = "Santander"}
    }, "value", "text", 0))
    </td>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

E o *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(EscolhaBancoViewModel viewModel) 
{
    // O valor vai aparecer em viewModel.EscolhaBanco
}
```

Comment: e para pegar o SelectedItem ou Index e fazer uma verificação com ele, dá pra fazer com o drop assim ?

Comment: @AndreeH O que você gostaria de verificar?

Comment: Eu tenho 2 métodos, um pra retornar informações do bradesco ou santander, conforme a escolha, com isso, preciso fazer essa verificação de acordo com a escolha do drop e acessar o metodo certo.

Comment: Sim. Você pretende fazer um `POST` ou vai usar Ajax?

Comment: Isso só vai acontecer após clicar em uma ActionLink.

Comment: Então é `POST`. Vou ampliar a resposta.

Comment: Isso, é post. Beleza.

Comment: @AndreeH Veja agora.

Comment: a actionlink no meu código, está passando um parametro. E agora ?

Comment: Atualize a pergunta, colocando esta parte nela.

Comment: Pronto @Cigano Morrison Mendez.

Comment: o chat aqui é bloqueado. :S

Comment: @AndreeH Não tem problema. Qualquer coisa abra outra pergunta que tento responder.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado.

Comment: Bolei um jeito aqui e deu certo. Só preciso da carteira do boleto do banco bradesco. Na dll que eu peguei não tem.